# python парсинг заголовка на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Не могу понять следующую ошибку:

```
l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, 1, _stacklevel=3,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

r = requests.get('https://jupyter.org/')
teext = soup.find("div", class_ = "col-md-6 description")
print(teext)
```

Comment: Вы используете soup.find(), но где вы создавали экземпляр класса BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get('https://jupyter.org/')
teext = soup(r.content, 'html.parser').find_all("div", class_="col-md-6 description")
print(teext)
```

Объект для поиска забыли указать